# Код сильно тормозит загрузку сайта, помогите исправить

Tags: php, html, curl, оптимизация-сайтов, pagespeed-insights

Вот результат тестирования. Что сделать, чтоб нагрузка не была такой и сайт грузился быстрее. Заранее спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а нельзя получение данных от удаленного сервиса по крону настроить? как часто они там меняются, на какой промежуток кэшируете? а вижу 6 мин

Comment: У вас узкое место - доступ к сторонним ресурсам по `curl`. Единственный вариант, который мне видится, - вынести логику загрузки данных со сторонних ресурсов на сторону клиента и отображать по готовности

Comment: @rjhdby да там судя по диаграмме половина уходит еще и на загрузку и декодирование. Мб имеет смысл кэшировать  не json, а результат. не все же с этог json-на нужно. сериализовать объекты обычным образом мб.

Comment: @teran  Кэширую раз в 30 минут

Comment: @teran Это как "сериализовать объекты обычным образом"?

Comment: `serialize()` использовать.

Comment: @teran все данные каждые 20 минут меняются.

Comment: ну я к тому, что загрузка данных с файла и их десериализация занимает тоже прилично времени. Поэтому если можно  сократить объем данных, кэшировать только то что требуется по факту. Ну или попробовать другие форматы хранения, кроме исходного json.

Comment: @rjhdby как это реализовать на примере моего кода?

Comment: в общем логику загрузки/обновления и подготовки данных выносите из основного кода.

Comment: @teran Спасибо, попробую найти программиста, кто перепишет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Больше всего времени у вас занимает загрузка данных со сторонних ресурсов. Фактически есть два пути улучшения ситуации. А лучше использовать сразу оба.

1. Вынести кеширование в фон, как совершенно верно заметил @teran. Напишите скрипт, который будет заниматься только тем, что запрашивать сторонние ресурсы, обрабатывать результаты и складывать данные в файл или в БД и настройте его запуск в планировщике с необходимым интервалом.
2. Получать информацию для каждого внешнего источника асинхронно. Для этого создайте API с тремя методами, каждый из которых будет отдавать информацию от одного из источников и загружайте эти данные посредством JS непосредственно с клиента. Кроме увеличения скорости получения данных профит будет еще и в том, что страница пользователю будет показана практически мнгновенно (не забудьте прогресс-бары загрузки), что людям обычно нравится.

При этом следует помнить о том, что во время обновления кеша может получиться так, что файл с данными в какой-то момент будет некорректен. Т.е., например, заполнен только на половину. Это решается таким образом - кеширующий скрипт пишет данные во временный файл, который в последствии переименовываете в основной файл кеша (переименовывание - атомарная операция). В случае же кеша в БД следует использовать транзакции.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую найти программиста, кто перепишет.